# Let the user choose a theme [Android]

Tags: android, themes

I'm have an app i'm working on in which I'm trying to let the user change the "theme" or the look of the layouts. Like how some apps have the option where you can pick the "Light theme" or the "Dark Theme".

So basically I need help with the following:

- Are there any built in themes in Android that I can use?
- How do I get access to the themes?
- Any other useful information. I'm really new at this.

Comment: MAke your own two or three different layouts and when user change the layout just call setLayout() method and voila you got light dark everything!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would need to create your themes using the standard [Android theme/style](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) process, and build a list of the Themes/resources you want to make available to the user (e.g., "Light" => R.style.MyLightTheme, "Dark" => R.style.MyDarkTheme, "iPhone" => R.style.iOSTheme).  Expose that list of available themes to the user as, for example, a `ListPreference` in a Preferences/Settings screen.

In your Activity's `onCreate()` method(s), before calling `setContentView()`, set the theme using [`this.setTheme(customTheme);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme(int))

`customTheme` would come from the [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) as mentioned above

Comment: This is exactly what I do in my own app.